# React Native Facebook API batch requests

Tags: facebook-graph-api, react-native

I'm struggling with the batch request to the Facebook API in React Native. For a single request this tutorial works fine : https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk.

But can I create a batch request. Using GraphRequestBatch does not seem to work. Adding up request with addRequest() neither (such as suggested in https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/issues/185).

Please help! I would like to send a batch of request with the same node and same edges, excepts only the time span changes.

Each request will look like :

```
const request = new GraphRequest('me/',
 {
 accessToken: accessToken,
 parameters: {
    fields: {
      string: 'posts.since(t1).until(t2).limit(n){likes.summary(true)}'
            }
          }
      },
 responseInfoCallback);
```

I tried creating several requests, each with a different t1 and t2, then add them up like this :

```
const graphmanager = new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(requesta);
graphmanager.addRequest(requestb);
...
graphmanager.start();
```

But only the first request gets executed.

Thanks for the help!